# How do I find a record in Cosmos EF by its childs property?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb

I have a cosmos database that I am querying with Entity Framework Core.

I have an account object which has many users. I need to return a user by its email property and also return its parent account object. I have tried the following but it complains that the query can not be translated.

```
var account = await (from a in _context.Accounts where a.AccountUsers.Any(m => m.Email == email) select a).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Accounts DbSet is set to OwnsMany Users.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().OwnsMany(t => t.AccountUsers);
```

How do I get the information I need?

Here is an example of a document in cosmos

```
{
    "AccountId": "07c86927-5dff-4fe3-89bf-3e3ac2f35523",
    "AccountName": "Test",
    "AccountType": 0,
    "Discriminator": "Account",
    "IsEnabled": true,
    "id": "Account|07c86927-5dff-4fe3-89bf-3e3ac2f35523",
    "AccountUsers": [
        {
            "UserId": "95dafa6e-37af-490a-a5b0-965b597d2db6",
            "Email": "email",
            "FirstName": "testFirstName",
            "IsEnabled": false,
            "LastName": "testLastName",
            "Password": "testPass"
        }
    ],
    "_rid": "7K9MAKjomF4CAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/7K9MAA==/colls/7K9MAKjomF4=/docs/7K9MAKjomF4CAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"1400452d-0000-1000-0000-6151fdd40000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1632763348
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Using Linq I would do something like this (I'm sorry as I'm not very used to the syntax you are using, even though from context I understand most of it, the only bit I'm missing is `select a`)

```
public class newAccountViewModel
{
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    ...
    public IList<newAccountUserViewModel> AccountUsers { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class newAccountUserViewModel
{
    public int UserId{ get; set; }
    ...
}
```

```
var account = _context.Accounts
                      .Where(a=> a.AccountUsers.Any(m => m.Email == email))
                      .Select(a=> newAccountViewModel
                      {
                          AccountId = a.Id
                          ...
                          AccountUsers = a.AccountUsers.Select(au=> newAccountUserViewModel
                          {
                              UserId = au.UserId
                              ...
                          })
                          .ToList()
                      })
                      .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Comment: I am pretty sure Any() is not supported for Cosmos DB yet... Which is the issue I am having. I will give your code a go though just in case.

Comment: Nope, it can not translate that query.